# Suppose the point (X, Y ) is chosen randomly from the region bounded by the lines x = 0, y = 1, and y..

Tags: probability

I don't know how to do this problem but I tried to do it two ways, both of which I have no idea if they are correct or not. All I know is the answer is f(x,y)=2. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the point $(X,Y)$ is chosen *uniformly* from the triangular region $T$ means (by definition) that the joint probability density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ of the coordinates $X,Y$ is constant inside that region
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=C.
$$ 
How to determine this constant? Imposing normalization, i.e.
$$
\iint_T dx dy\ f_{X,Y}(x,y) =1\Rightarrow C\times (\text{area of }T) =1.
$$
The area of the triangle is given by $1/2\times 1\times 1=1/2$, so the constant $C=2$.

---

Your second approach to the problem is not really understandable (it is not clear what $x$ is supposed to represent. On top of this, $x^2=2$ clearly does not imply $x=2$!). Your first approach starts from the rather bad notation
$$
\int_0^x\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}bh\ dy dx\ .
$$
First, you should never use the same symbol ($x$) for an integration variable, and a limit of integration. Second, when you have a double integral, one of which has one (or both limits of integration) depending on the *other* variable, you shoud be very clear about which integral should be performed *first* [in your way of writing it, the outer integral depends on $x$, so it seems the final result of the integration should still depend on $x$!]. Third, if $b$ and $h$ are meant to represent base and height of the triangular region, then you don't need *any* integration at all (you are already computing the area of that region!). If you really want to use integrals to compute the area of that triangle (it is a longer way, but may be instructive) you should write
$$
\int_T dx dy=\int_0^1 dx \int_0^x dy=\int_0^1 dx\ x=\frac{x^2}{2}\Big|_0^1=\frac{1}{2}
$$
as before.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think your bounds are wrong.
   Mathematically, since you that the points are distributed "uniformly", the height of the volume is flat. So, let $f(x,y) = h$. this is what we are solving for. Using calculus, we have
   $$\int_0^1\int_x^1f(x,y)\,dydx = \int_0^1\int_x^1 h\,dydx = 1.$$
   Notice that your bounds are wrong. After solving, we find that $h  =2$.
2. I don't know what you did for the bottom one. But geometrically, we know the volume of the wedge is one. The area of triangle is 
   $$\frac{1}{2}\times 1\times 1 = \frac{1}{2}$$
   To get the volume, we need to multiply this by some height $h$, and we know it is equal to $1$, hence
   $$\frac{1}{2}h = 1\implies h = 2.$$
   So intuitively, we know that the joint density over this region is $f(x,y) = 2$.